# I am looking for that one specific tutorial on beautiful TikZ histograms

Tags: tikz-pgf, tutorials

this is a rather loosely related question, but would anyone happen to have the link to that one tutorial for "beautiful" [histograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) with TikZ? IIRC it was about how to draw a good-looking histogram with TikZ.

Sites I've tried so far:

- http://www.latex-community.org
- http://www.howtotex.com
- http://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful
- http://www.reddit.com/r/latex

... and lots of various combinations of relevant terms in google. However, I haven't been successful.

From what I remember, the final histogram did not have a grid and at the y-values 0.5, 1.0, ... there were little white spaces in the bars. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean the Tufte-style bar charts, by any chance? http://latex-community.org/know-how/437-tufte-charts

Comment: Yes. Oh wow, how on earth did I not find that article... well, thank you!

Comment: @henry he wrote it :)

Comment: @Jake: My suggestion here (and it might be really localized...) is to replicate your blog post here as an answer.